# How do i directly replicate data into salesforce account without using postman application

Tags: java, salesforce

I am importing some information (includes accounts and contacts)
Anyone have advice on the best methodology for doing the import?
Any experience with this import in specific or importing data into Salesforce in general would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should decide is it one time migration of data, or it's iterative process which is an integral part of your solution.

In first case you can use any ETL tools that supports Salesforce integration. There are a lot of them - Talend, Pentaho Kettle, Jitterbit and many others. You can find more information about on [Awesome Salesforce page](https://github.com/mailtoharshit/awesome-salesforce#etl-tools).

In second case you need to implement integration API. Salesforce provides few approaches for API:

- [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/REST_API) - Access objects in your organization using REST
- [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/SOAP_API) - Integrate your organization’s data with other applications using SOAP
- [Bulk API](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Bulk_API) - Load or delete large numbers of records
- [Streaming API](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Streaming_API) - Provide a stream of data reflecting data changes
  in your organization.